# What are the hypotheses in Levi's monotone convergence theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Today I read monotone convergence theorem , dominated convergence theorem and fatou's lemma

And I need some help

We know the dominated convergence theorem in Measure theory

In its proof we establish a sequence $h_n=2g - |f_n-f|$ the sequence $(h_n)$ of positive measurable function and it converges to $(2g)$ then by fatou's lemma we complete the proof .

The question that presents itself : the sequence $(h_n)$  of positive measurable function and converges to $(2g)$ and I think the sequence $(h_n)$ is increasing because $|f_n-f|$ converges to $0$ So $ |f_1-f| \ge |f_2-f| \ge |f_3-f| \ge |f_4-f| \ge |f_5-f| \ge ....$ then  $h_1 \le h_2 \le h_3 \le ...$ so why I don't use monotone convergence theorem to complete the proof .

The sequence $(h_n)$ increasing or not if increasing I need the proof if not I need an example shows the sequence $(h_n)$ is not necessary to be increasing so I can't use monotone convergence theorem

Comment: $|f_n-f|$ may be non-decreasing, making $h_n$ non-increasing

Comment: @Tryss I need just an example shows the $|f_n-f|$  non - decreasing

Comment: On $[0,2\pi]$ take $f=0$ and $f_n(x) = \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$, then for a given $n_0$, $f_{n_0}( \frac{\pi}{2n_0} ) =0$, but $f_{2n_0}( \frac{\pi}{2n_0} ) =-\frac{1}{n}$, making $|f_n-f|$ non decreasing

Comment: @Tryss you mean $|f_n-f|=\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: $|f_n-f|$ **is not** equal to $\frac{1}{n}$. $|f_n-f|$ takes values in $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ and is obviously not constant. What my argument is, is that if $|f_n-f|$ is decreasing, then **for every** $x$, if $n > m$, then $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq |f_m(x)-f(x)|$. Here I show that for this function, there exist $x_0 = \frac{\pi}{2n_0}$ and $n_1 = 2n_0 > n_0$ such that $|f_{2n_0}(x)-f(x)| > |f_{n_0}(x)-f(x)|$, hence $|f_n-f|$ is not decreasing

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the sequence $|f_n-f|$ to be decreasing to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem (that's basically the point of using DCT rather than the Monotone Convergence Theorem). Example I thought up on the spot: take an alternating series,
$$ 1-x+x^2-\dotsb $$
which you can write as a convergent sequence of partial sums,
$$ S_n(x) := \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-x)^{k} = \frac{1-(-x)^{n+1}}{1+x}. $$
These tend pointwise to $\frac{1}{1+x}$ when $|x|<1$. Note the sequence is not uniform, since it is alternately above and below its limiting value. Then the DCT says that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 S_n(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 \left( \lim_{n \to \infty}  S_n(x) \right) \, dx \\
= \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x} = \left[ \log{(1+x)} \right]_0^1 = \log{2}. $$

(Oh yes, you'll want a dominating function, of course. It is easy to see that $S_n(x) \leqslant 1$ on this interval.)

---

(Of course, one equality further back is the sum of integrals
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \int_0^1 x^k \, dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}, $$
so in this case, the DCT is a sophisticated alternative to the alternating series test that actually gives the value of the sum we all knew.)

Comment: I want to prove the dominate convergence theorem

Comment: What did you write ?